# Missing scrollbars for 100% fixed width/height iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to load a responsive site in a maximized (width and height = 100%) iframe and then fix the width and height from 100% to the corresponding pixel-values, so if the outer window gets shrinked, the responsive-site stays at the previous maximized-dimensions.

The following code works, but if you make the window smaller, there are no scrollbars.

How can I make the scrollbars appear automatically, like overflow:auto? I do need 100% initial dimensions, because my responsive iframe content is very old and makes problems while resizing, so I can't resize the iframe later on.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
 * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0; 
 }

 #wrapper { position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; }
 #wrapper iframe { width:100%; height:100%; border:0 none; }

    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
 <!--
 $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('#wrapper').width($('#wrapper').outerWidth());
      $('#wrapper').height($('#wrapper').outerHeight());
 });

 //-->
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
 <iframe id="myFrame" src="https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/" frameborder="0">
   <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
 </iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `overflow:scroll` always shows scrollbars. Unless I don't understand what you're up to.

Comment: Where do I have to assign the "overflow:scroll"? If I add it to #wrapper there're two vertical scrollbars and if I shrink the window, both disappear. I want to have automatic scrollbars.

Comment: After a bit of experimenting, I found the issue is caused by the fact that you set the width and height of the #wrapper explicitly (to a size in pixels) at the start. So the question is, why do you do that? Your snippet works perfectly fine if you don't do that.

Comment: I do that, because my iframe content should always stay maximized if the outer window gets shrinked. In this case the scrollbars should appear automatically. I think the problem is the "position:fixed", but without that I don't know how to make the iframe's height 100%.

Comment: The iframe is already maximised by the `width: 100%; height:100%` in the CSS. However, you then set the width with JavaScript to a fixed amount, and then the iframe can't grow or shrink any more. That is what causes the issue, not the `position:fixed`.

Comment: Ok, but is there any other way to maximize the iframe (width and height=100%) without using javascript first, and then fix it at this dimensions (javascript allowed), so if the window gets shrinked, the scrollbars appear automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself. The trick was to set body and html to 100% height, remove the position:fixed of the wrapper and add "display:block" to the iframe. Without the display:block there was a little space at the end of the iframe, so the vertical scrollbar was always visible.

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;    
}

#wrapper { width:100%; height:100%; }
#wrapper iframe { display: block; width:100%; height:100%; border:0 none;}
```